# Groovy Elasticsearch Client

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I am using ES in a grails 2.5.1 application.

My old dependencies are the following:

```
   runtime 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:1.3.7'
   runtime 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-client-groovy:1.3.2'
```

I have updated my mappings, and my system ES has been changed to `1.7.1`. 
The following dependencies appear to work fine:

```
    runtime 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:1.7.1'
    runtime 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-client-groovy:1.3.2'
```

I want to also update my groovy client version. The only repository I can find is the following: `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-groovy:1.7.0`

Although this seems to be a rather plain wrapper around the Java  client,according to the [github repository](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-groovy).

The result of this is that my existing code is no longer working, giving exception about GNode and GClient not existing (I also searched the repo to make sure). BUT on elastic documentation, these classes [exist](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/groovy-api/master/client.html) . I have been trying google and [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch) but cannot find any other repository for the groovy client.

Example error:

> unable to resolve class org.elasticsearch.groovy.node.GNode

```
org.elasticsearch.groovy.node.GNode esnode = ESWrapperService.getNode()
org.elasticsearch.groovy.client.GClient esclient = esnode.getClient()

  try {
    if ( (params.q && params.q.length() > 0) || params.rectype) {

      params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 15, 100)
      params.offset = params.offset ? params.int('offset') : 0

      def query_str = buildQuery(params,field_map)


      def search = esclient.search{
        indices grailsApplication.config.aggr.es.index ?: "default"
        source {
          from = params.offset
          size = params.max
          sort = params.sort?[
            ("${params.sort}".toString()) : [ 'order' : (params.order?:'asc') ]
          ] : []

          query {
            query_string (query: query_str)
          }
          facets {
            consortiaName {
              terms {
                field = 'consortiaName'
                size = 25
              }
            }
            cpname {
              terms {
                field = 'cpname'
                size = 25
              }
            }
            type {
              terms {
                field = 'rectype'
              }
            }
            startYear {
              terms {
                field = 'startYear'
                size = 25
              }
            }
            endYear {
              terms {
                field = 'endYear'
                size = 25
              }
            }
          }

        }

      }

      if ( search?.response ) {
        result.hits = search.response.hits
        result.resultsTotal = search.response.hits.totalHits

        // We pre-process the facet response to work around some translation issues in ES
        if ( search.response.facets != null ) {
          result.facets = [:]
          search.response.facets.facets.each { facet ->
            def facet_values = []
            facet.value.entries.each { fe ->
              facet_values.add([term: fe.term,display:fe.term,count:"${fe.count}"])
            }
            result.facets[facet.key] = facet_values
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      log.debug("No query.. Show search page")
    }
  }
  finally {
    try {
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
      log.error("problem",e);
    }
  }
```

**Update**

I just checked the `preface` section of the documentation that points to `elasticsearch-groovy` repository, which makes this even more confusing..

Comment: It looks like I missed the release for ES 1.7.1 Groovy client. ES 1.7.0 client is compatible with ES 1.7.1, so feel free to get it working with that for now while I make the release of ES 1.7.1.

Comment: Critically, ES Groovy 1.4+ were a major rewrite of the ES Groovy client. Things like `GNode` no longer exist in the new code base.

Comment: Right, so that means that the documentation is outdated ?

Comment: Yes. Check out the updated documents in the repo https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-groovy/tree/1.7/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the documentation is out of date. I had the same issue, but using @pickypg's suggestion tried the [newer documentation on github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-groovy/tree/1.7/docs), and it worked.